# Identify a bollywood movie where a man changes to woman

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching a Hindi movie where a man becomes woman after he commented badly about girls. Then an accident happened the next day when he awakes from his sleep. He turns into a woman.

Slowly when leading a girls life he understands how difficult a girls life is! I remember a scene where he becomes very upset when he understands that every guy in his office was seeing at his legs. Those were not covered as he was not accustomed to feel shy. But then he understands he should be shy when he is in a girls form!

Comment: Do you remember actors or year it released?

Comment: It must be released post 2000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be [Mr Ya Miss](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Ya_Miss).

In this movie Aaftab Shivdasani got killed and restored as a woman Antara Mali and his best friend acted by Ritesh Deshmukh, got fall in love with her and help in finding the killer which may be Divya Datta.

Comment: It was an absolute comedy, but only saw part of the film. now going to see the movie! :)

Comment: Absolute legendary answer _/\ _